# Ubuntu 13.10 : Why is my wifi disabled everytime I reboot my system

Tags: boot

I am facing a weird issue where my wifi is disabled on booting or rebooting and I need to run

```
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

to get it to work again. I dont have a problem with this but I am confused as to why I need to do this every time I boot in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is *brcmsmac* blacklisted somewhere? The usual suspect is /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf. Remove it:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

You can also ask the system to load brcmsmac automatically on boot:

```
sudo -i
echo brcmsmac  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```